# C File Access Word Count

Tags: c

I am having an issue that i can not seem to figure out. I have to count the number of lines and characters and words from a file. However my code below counts new lines as characters when it shouldn't and does not give the correct number of words. For instance the file

> "f1.txt"
>
> this is the first line
>
> this    is the 2nd

out puts

> Line Count : 2
> Word Count : 9
> Character Count : 30

When the word count should is correct, but it counts the new lines. When i take out the '\n' from the

```
if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') {
        ++wordcount;
}
```

portion of code, it will give me 7 words which is not correct. The code of my program is below. Any hints in the direction to correct my code will be helpful(:

```
if ( fp ) {
        // Repeat until End Of File character is reached.
        while ((ch=getc(fp)) != EOF) {
                if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\n') {
                        ++charcount;
                }
                if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') {
                        ++wordcount;
                }
                if (ch == '\n') {
                        ++linecount;
                }
        }
        if (charcount > 0) {
                ++wordcount;
        }
}
```

Comment: There is much more errors. if you have more spaces between words it will count them as well as words. Start the debugger and try to debug. Also make the file more complicated for the program.

Comment: See `getword()` from [cflow's wc](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/html_node/Source-of-wc-command.html). The trick to process the stream until we find a word (they are strictly looking for alphabetical characters), and then process until we are no longer in a word. Toggling between these two modes (word vs. non-word) makes it easy to track the significance of the character.

Comment: what if there are consecutive `spaces` in file, your logic will count those also as a `word`, isn't it ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739596/why-is-my-implementation-of-wc-off-by-one-word

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is incorrect. How come you're conditionally incrementing the value of the `charcount` variable here?

```
if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\n') {
    ++charcount;
}
```

If `ch` does not equal `EOF`, you should be incrementing the `charcount` variable because everything from a new line to a number is a character.

```
while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    ++charcount;

    ...
```

For the number of lines, all you have to do is check whether `ch == '\n'`. This is the only thing you have to do to keep track of the number of lines you've read.

```
if (ch == '\n') {
    ++linecount;
}
```

For the word counter you only need to modify your code in two small ways. First, you need to add in a check for `ch == \t` because this should also count as a separator for the word counter.

Second, as chrisayrock said in the comments when he linked `cflow's wc`, all you really have to do is just keep track of when you are or aren't in a word. Rather than use all the stuff they used in their implementation though, I think we should kick it old school, Kernighan and Ritchie Style. [See Section 1.5.4 - Word Counting](http://www.learntosolveit.com/cprogramming/sec_1.5.4_word_counting.html) of their book - it's this exact problem. They use a variable to keep track of whether you're currently in a word or not. I used `readingWord`, and if I read a "new word" character, I set the reading word variable to false, since obviously a "new word" character is the delimiter between words.

On the flip side, when you first get to a legal word character, the reading word variable was already false, so now we set it to true and we increment our words counter. Notice that since we've set the reading words character to true, if won't reset until we read in another word delimiter, i.e... `' '`, `'\n'`, or `'\t`'. In this way, we make sure that we're only counting words once.

Here is the code, let me know if you have any questions. I didn't read my data from file, I just typed it in, because I saw that's not where the problem was, but let me know if you want me to modify the input, I'll set up the program to read from file as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = 0;

    int characters = 0;
    int lines = 0;
    int words = 0;

    currentlyInWord = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++characters;

        if (c == '\n') {
            ++lines;
        }

        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            readingWord = 0;
        } else if (readingWord == 0) {
            readingWord = 1;
            ++words;
        }
    }

    printf("Characters: %d\nWords: %d\nLines: %d\n\n", characters, words, lines);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Input:

```
This is a test, hello!
My name is Jeff.
I like to program in C.
```

Output:

```
Characters: 64
Words: 15
Lines: 3
```

As a side note, I really recommend you read [The C Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) by Kernighan and Ritchie. It's a phenomenal book that breaks down every aspect of the C programming language.